# How do i create a new column in a python dataframe using the equivalent of excel averageifs

Tags: python, average

I have a python dataframe with the following columns : Year Month Date DayofWeek SaleVolume
How do i create a new column AvgbyDay which is the average SaleVolume (avg by Year, month and DayofWeek). I can do this using groupby but i would like to display it in the dataframe. I am looking for the equivalent of the excel `averageifs($E:$E,$A:$A,A[i],$B:$B,B[i],$D:$D,D[i])`

Comment: Please provide a MRE with code you have tried and a sample of your data so that people can actually help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add a column with `groupby`, one way is to use `transform`:

```
df['AvgbyDay'] = df.groupby('DayofWeek')['SaleVolume'].transform('mean')
df['AvgbyDay'] = df.groupby(['Year','Month','Date','Day'])['SaleVolume'].transform('mean')
```

If you want to create a **separate** column with the average sales volume for Year, Month, Date and Day, you can use a `for loop` and do:

```
time_cols = ['Year','Month','Date','DayofWeek']
for col in df[time_cols]:
    df[col+'_average_sales'] = df.groupby(col)['DayofWeek'].transform('mean')
```

Pick what you need!